# AV Foundation Framework video quality checking

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

**What I Did**:- I have done a project camera video recording app using **AV Foundation Framework** in swift..

I have completed till recording and saving the video

After I took the video and **I want to check the quality** before saving the video.

I am using **AVplayer** to play the recorded video

**OR**

Tell me how to get the video resolution after recording the video using swift..

If I got that means I will check my Video Quality depends on the resolution

please guide me to do this..

Comment: what you've tried pl. post code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned you are using AVFoundation and doing the recording, I assume you do have an instance of `AVAsset` (or you have an `NSURL` pointing the file location), then you can get the video tracks in the `AVAsset` and then have the video size.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetTrack/naturalSize

```
// if you have the NSURL pointing to the file, you can build an AVAsset by this
let asset: AVAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: fileURL)

// get the first track
if let track = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)?.first {

  let size: CGSize = track.naturalSize

  // then you can have the width and height
  let width = size.width
  let height = size.height
}
```

As a side note, apart from resolution of the videos, there are other factors like the bitrate of the video, which can also affect the quality. More to be found in the apple documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMFormatDescription/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CMVideoFormatDescriptionRef

Comment: hello. Thanks for answer. Do you know why for this url `https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8 ` always get `nil`? I also check all another media types (`audio`, `metadata` etc), but have the same result - `nil`.